# Fetching a value from a PHP array

Tags: php

Sounds a silly question but Im having trouble fetching a value from an array.

The array is :

```
 ["roles"]=> array(1) { 
   [0]=> string(13) "administrator" 
 }
```

Im trying to get the User Role as a variable.

Comment: just `$arr['roles'][0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your Array:**

```
$arr = array("roles" => array("administrator"));

Array
(
    [roles] => Array
        (
            [0] => administrator
        )

)
```

**Process:**

```
echo $arr['roles'][0]; //administrator
```

Comment: Yep, thats kind of what i though, im getting the following error Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_User as array in /path

Comment: your given array is associative, if the array is object then you have to use `->` sign. ex: `$arr->roles[0]`

Comment: post your array of `print_r` version.